# где скачать c# для разработки Android?

Tags: c#, android

где скачать бесплатную программу с# для Android  разработки?

Comment: А разве в Community версии нет возможности писать под Android?

Comment: Можно и в Community: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/

Answer (score 1):

visual studio community android app development c# - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/android/

Для шарпа лучше студии Вы не найдете - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

Но советую покапать проф. версию.